# Absolute path to webroot

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

For email attachments I would like to get the direct path to the webroot folder. Something like this: /var/www/vhosts/.../webroot

Is there an constant or an function defined for that in Cake?

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WWW_DIR`, it's defined in /app/webroot/index.php along with some other useful constants.

Comment: Note that in current versions of CakePHP it's WWW_ROOT - see also http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

As @almcnicoll said, in current versions of Cakephp (v > 2.x), the constant is:

```
WWW_ROOT
```